# Angular 6 - ngx-mqtt 6.7.0 - Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, mqtt, ionic4

I am using **ngx-mqtt** in an Ionic 4 project with this dependencies.

I have followed the instruction's on official site: https://sclausen.github.io/ngx-mqtt/#description

I was testing it on test.mosquitto.org:8080. **It worked.**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~6.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "ngx-mqtt": "^6.4.1",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }
```

After update to "ngx-mqtt": "^6.7.0". It started throwing this error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I recreated the error on a clean angular project, it has the same problem.

I am attaching gist to show.

https://gist.github.com/FrankMa1/ff2118fff681a7fc156a60d7b8eeae37

I do not know what to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be its server side problem because

CONNECTION_REFUSED is error occures when the port is closed, but it could be rejected because SSL is failing authentication.

However the refused message is likely a server side problem, (usually port closed).

-- check port of server and check server is running properly.

-- Chrome doesn't allow unsecure websocket (ws) connections to localhost 
   (only wss, so you should setup a TLS certificate for your local 
   web/websocket server). However the same should work fine with Firefox.

-- Usually WebRTC requires a secure connection (that is https). The error 
   you have got is due to TLS/SSL certificates occupied, may be they are 
   not properly configured in your project. Provide a valid TLS/SSL 
   certificate and also configure it correctly in project, then it will 
   work without the above error.

Try following secure wss

```
wss://test.mosquitto.org:8080/
```

Comment: Thank you for good recommendations. I have tried to connect via wss://test.mosquitto.org:8081
only changing to wss and it didn't help.
Firefox has the same error.
I don't know how could I set up a TLS/SSL certificate in a project.